# Resize GridColumn by dragging its header's left edge

Tags: devexpress, xtragrid

On the [GridColumn](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraGridColumnsGridColumntopic) object there is the [OptionsColumn.AllowSize](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridColumnsOptionsColumn_AllowSizetopic) property, which lets the user to resize a column by dragging the column header's right edge. That works fine.

Now lets suppose I have a fixed column to the right in my grid:

[image]

But in this situation it's a kind of difficult to resize the fixed column, because I can do that only using its header's right edge.

So my question is:

Is it possible to allow a user to resize a column by dragging the column header's **left** edge?

Comment: I had a similar problem and not solved . I had to swap the last two columns and then change the width  ...